# Rails/Rails3 SQL query, "LIKE" doesn't work with datetimes properly?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Are rails SQL queries actually compatible with datetimes?

For example, if I do:

```
User.where("email LIKE ?", "%.com%")
```

I would expect to (and do) get back a list of all users with a ".com" email address.

However, if I do:

```
User.where("created_at LIKE ?","%2011%")
```

I get back nothing, even though I can see that there are users created this year. In point of fact, sometimes i get gibberish back (for example, I might get stuff (with seemingly nothing in common) back for %20%, but nothing back for %30% even though I know there are dates with a 30 in them), which makes me think the "LIKE" is applying to something I don't see/care about (maybe some sort of ID?)

Are LIKES for string only? Is there some way I can do something similar for date times, in rails (I'm sure there's some way to do it in mysql, but can rails also handle it?)

Specifically, I want to use this in a scope, similar to:

```
 scope :by_date, lambda {|date| where("created_at LIKE ?",date)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, datetime values are stored as integers.
LIKE  operator works on strings.

You can try using CONVERT() or CAST() or even CONCAT().

Something like:

```
 CONVERT(created_at, VARCHAR(20))
```

Comment: Forgot to add, for comparing datetimes it is better to use BETWEEN operator. Using %2011% with call to CONVERT, could _potentially_ result in false positives like when you have 20th of November.

Answer (score 2):

```
dt = Date.new(2011,1,1)
User.where(['created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?',dt,dt+1.year])
```

produces

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (created_at >= '2011-01-01' AND created_at < '2012-01-01')
```

Which is a better way to handle datetimes IMHO